# Error patch App Roles on App Registration using Graph API v5: App role with identifier must have at least one value specified for 'allowedMemberTypes'

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I use Graph API v5 to update App Roles on an existing App Registration and get the following error when I apply the patch on an App Registration that already has a App Role:

- `ODataError.Code: Request_BadRequest`
- `ODataError.Message: App role with identifier '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' must have at least one value specified for 'allowedMemberTypes'.`

I use the following code:

```cs
// Create Graph Service Client using DefaultAzureCredential for my tenant.
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        TenantId = "my_tenant_id",
    }));

var appRegistrationObjectId = "object_id_my_app_registration";

var applicationClient = graphClient.Applications[appRegistrationObjectId];

var application = await applicationClient
    .GetAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

application.AppRoles.Add(new AppRole
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Value = "DummyName",
    DisplayName = "Dummy display name",
    Description = "Description of this dummy app role",
    AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string> { "Application" },
    IsEnabled = true,
});

await applicationClient
    .PatchAsync(application)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

When I run this code for the first time on an App Registration without App Roles, it works as expected; the App Role with name `DummyName` is added.

When I run it again and add a new app role (e.g. `Dummy2`) I get the aforementioned error. I don't understand where the default Guid in the error message is coming from, because if I inspect the values of the AppRoles list in the debugger I see 2 AppRole instances, both having a unique Guid?

Package version: 5.1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is because you serialize the same graph object twice. Since the upgrade to V5 all models within the SDK are no longer simple DTOs. They are stateful objects remembering which properties are changed since the last serialization, which is also described in the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/upgrade-to-v5.md#backing-store).

If you take a look into the debugger at the properties you see all values as expected, but if you take a look into the property *BackingStore* you'll find out it holds a *Dictionary<bool, object>*. The boolean value describes which values should be serialized.

To better understand this behaviour take a look at this code example:

```
public static void Main()
{
    var group = new Group{Id = "abc"};
    var client = new GraphServiceClient(DelegatedTokenCredential.Create((_, _) => new AccessToken()));
    var request = client.Groups["abc"].ToPatchRequestInformation(group);

    Console.WriteLine("First:  " + ExtractBody(request.Content));
    // Output: First:  {"id":"abc","@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.group"}

    request = client.Groups["abc"].ToPatchRequestInformation(group);
    Console.WriteLine("Second: " + ExtractBody(request.Content));
    // Output: Second: {}

    // Enforce value re-serialization on next call
    group.Id = group.Id
    request = client.Groups["abc"].ToPatchRequestInformation(group);
    Console.WriteLine("Third:  " + ExtractBody(request.Content));
    // Output: Third:  {"id":"abc"}
}

private static string ExtractBody(Stream stream)
{
    using var ms = new MemoryStream();
    using var sr = new StreamReader(ms);
    stream.CopyTo(ms);
    ms.Position = 0;
    return sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
First:  {"id":"abc","@odata.type":"#microsoft.graph.group"}
Second: {}
Third:  {"displayName":"def"}
```

As you can see, we use all the time the very same `group` object, but the body only contains all elements since the last serialization. This will always be problematic if you need to re-send information. In that case you have to re-apply the very same value to the property to declare a *value change* as you can see in the commented code above.

In your concrete example it should be sufficient to add the following lines before your next call:

```
application.AppRoles = application.AppRoles
foreach (var role in application.AppRoles)
{
    role.Id = role.Id;
    role.AllowedMemberTypes = role.AllowedMemberTypes;
}
```

Comment: Interesting... was not aware of this backingstore. However, if I adjust the code in my original post and include the line `application.AppRoles = application.AppRoles` before I execute the PatchAsync call I still get the same error. I do see in the debugger the flag in the backingstore changes from false to true on the appRoles attribute when the included line is executed. However, when I execute PatchAsync(application) it still throws the same OData error as reported in my initial post.

Comment: `AppRoles` is a collection and each entry has its own backing store which must potentially be updated too. I updated my example code to also re-set the child properties accordingly.

Comment: Ah check! The updated approach works indeed as expected. Thanks for clarifying this mystery :)

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error as below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, make sure to pass valid **`allowedMemberTypes`** and pass the valid GUID of the App role:

[image]

When I used the below query, **I am able to update the App roles of the Application** successfully like below:

```json
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/ObjecIDofAPP

{
"appRoles": [
{
"allowedMemberTypes": [
"User",
"Application"
],
"description": "TestRole",
"displayName": "TestRole",
"id": "GUIDOfAppRole",
"isEnabled": true,
"origin": "Application",
"value": "test.write"
}
]
}
```

[image]

In the Azure Portal, App role got updated successfully:

[image]

**To do the same programmatically, you can make use of below code:**

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
var tenantId = "TenantID";
var clientId = "ClientID";
var clientSecret = "ClientSecret";

var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var requestBody = new Application
{
    AppRoles = new List<AppRole>
    {
        new AppRole
        {
            AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string>
            {
                "User",
                "Application",
            },
            Description = "TestRole1",
            DisplayName = "TestRole1",
            Id = Guid.Parse("71837dcd-4272-4ec6-b255-2d031efa090d"),
            IsEnabled = true,
            Origin = "Application",
            Value = "test.write",
        },
    },
};
var result = await graphClient.Applications["ObjectIDofApp"].PatchAsync(requestBody);
```

[image]

In the Azure Portal, **App role updated successfully** like below:

[image]

Comment: The solution you present here is not exactly my scenario, because here you update an existing App Role. I want to add an extra App Role to an existing App Registration. However, your answer did help me to play around a bit more and I landed on a working solution. See the answer I posted. The trick seems to create new AppRole instances based on the existing AppRoles returned by the GetAsync call, and then apply the patch passing the new List of AppRoles.

Comment: Glad to know that you resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reply by @Rukmini did trigger me to try passing a **new** list of AppRoles, which I populate with **new** AppRole instances based on the AppRoles returned by the GetAsync call. The following works for me:

```cs
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
    {
        TenantId = "my_tenant_id",
    }));

var appRegistrationObjectId = "my_app_registration_id";

var applicationClient = graphClient.Applications[appRegistrationObjectId];

var application = await applicationClient
    .GetAsync()
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

var appRoles = new List<AppRole>();
if (application?.AppRoles != null)
{
    // Create a new instance for each App Role returned in the GetAsync response
    appRoles = application.AppRoles.Select(x => new AppRole
    {
        Id = x.Id,
        Value = x.Value,
        DisplayName = x.DisplayName,
        Description = x.Description,
        AllowedMemberTypes = x.AllowedMemberTypes,
        IsEnabled = x.IsEnabled
    }).ToList();
}

appRoles.Add(new AppRole
{
    Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
    Value = "DummyName2",
    DisplayName = "Dummy display name 2",
    Description = "Description of this dummy app role 2",
    AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string> { "Application" },
    IsEnabled = true,
});

var requestBody = new Application()
{
    AppRoles = appRoles,
};

await applicationClient
    .PatchAsync(requestBody)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

I'm still a puzzled why I cannot simply add a new instance to `application.AppRoles` and then pass that list as AppRoles in the patch request, but instead need to create a new list and clone existing AppRoles.

**EDIT**: see the answer by Oliver explaining the concept of the backing store. Based on that answer the solution becomes like this:

```cs
    var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
        {
            TenantId = "my_tenant_id",
        }));
    
    var appRegistrationObjectId = "my_app_registration_object_id";
    
    var applicationClient = graphClient.Applications[appRegistrationObjectId];
    
    var application = await applicationClient
        .GetAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
    
    application.AppRoles.Add(new AppRole
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
        Value = "DummyName",
        DisplayName = "Dummy display name",
        Description = "Description of this dummy app role",
        AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string> { "Application" },
        IsEnabled = true,
    });
    
    // This part does the trick as explained by Oliver
    application.AppRoles = application.AppRoles;
    foreach (var role in application.AppRoles)
    {
        role.Id = role.Id;
        role.AllowedMemberTypes = role.AllowedMemberTypes;
    }
    
    await applicationClient
        .PatchAsync(application)
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add new appRole using code above. However, when i try to update the role I get a exception Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown.

```
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};

var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(
    tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);
var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

var applicationClient = graphClient.Applications["xxxxxx-xxxx-4da0-9cdf-1457927dc188"];


var appRoles = new List<AppRole>();
appRoles.Add(new AppRole
{
    Id = Guid.Parse("4ed7035e-dbaf-4963-9ac0-f1dcaac77xxx"),
    Value = "DummyName2",
    DisplayName = "Dummy display name 2",
    Description = "Description of this dummy app role 2",
    AllowedMemberTypes = new List<string> { "Application" },
    IsEnabled = false,
});

var requestBody = new Application()
{
    AppRoles = appRoles,
};

await applicationClient
    .PatchAsync(requestBody)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: The code in my answer works also when you update an existing role - I just checked a scenario where I update the display name of an existing app role which works as expected. Note the difference in your approach vs mine, is that you create a new list of app roles that does not include any of the existing app roles. I take the existing app roles from the applicationClient.GetAsync() as my starting point. Check if that helps.

Comment: I got it. Thanks! Basically for update we need to pass all the existing roles (getAsync) with updated values. Similarly when deleting all the existing roles minus the deleted app role needs to be passed.